# Kubernetes: gcePersistentDisk is not working

Tags: kubernetes, gce-persistent-disk

I am using `gcePersistentDisk` as volume in `kubernetes`. Currently all my VM , Disks are on under  same availability zone and account of `google cloud`. But still `gcePersistentDisk` is not mounting. Below are my deployment file.

## Stoage Class

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: ssd-sc 
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
reclaimPolicy: Retain # Retain storage even if we delete PVC
parameters:
  type: pd-ssd
```

## Volume

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: nfs-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: ssd-sc
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nfs-pv
spec:
  storageClassName: ssd-sc
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  gcePersistentDisk:
    pdName: nfs-disk
    fsType: ext4
```

## Service and Containers

```
   apiVersion: apps/v1 
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: apache-service
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: apache
  replicas: 1 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: apache
    spec:
     volumes:
      - name: service-pv-storage
        gcePersistentDisk:
          pdName: nfs-disk
          fsType: ext4  
     containers:
      - name: apache
        image: mobingi/ubuntu-apache2-php7:7.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/var/www/html"
          name: service-pv-storage

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: apache-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: apache
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 30751
  type: NodePort
```

### When i am using this deployment it give me following error on pod descriptions.

[image]

Note :- I am not using `kubernetes` google engine. I have setup my custom cluster.

Comment: Maybe include your StorageClass (since you're not using GKE), you PV and PVC YAML definition to have the full context.

Comment: i have added storage class also still the problem is same.

Comment: I meant to say, include it in your question, alongside your PV and PVC definitions to have better context and address the question.

Comment: Check i have edit the question.